# Checking out Git Submodules

Tags: git, version-control, github

I would like to do a partial checkout of a Git repository containing submodules.
Here is what I did to check the directory :

```
git clone --no-checkout git@github.com:MyOrganization/MyRepo.git --depth 1 --recurse-submodules
```

then:

```
cd MyRepo
git checkout HEAD MyDirectory/puppet/
```

This checkouts **MyDirectory/puppet** but does'nt retrieve the submodules contained in **MyDirectory/puppet/modules** directory...

Any idea how I could checkout the submodules ? If I could do it without having to run same command on every submodules directory that would be great, because modules list is going to change quite frequently.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

try:
`git submodule update --recursive`

Comment: The `--init` option is likely to be needed as well.

Comment: tried : git submodule update --init --recursive but I got this error message : 
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'provisioning/puppet/modules/apache'

Comment: In fact, when I use the option --no-checkout in the command git clone 
then I checkout dir from the repo, the .gitmodules is not created.